# TCP android Server not recieving first message from Java TCP client

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have a TCP Client in java and TCP server in android. Sending message form Server to Client works fine but when message is sent from Client to server(android)  it doesn't shows the message but when same process  is repeated second time, server shows the message i.e send button of java client should be pressed twice then only message is shown in the android app.

Java Client Code

```
//btn handelar to send message form textarea
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        String outputLine = txArea.getText ();
        System.out.println ("Client > " + outputLine);
        out.println (outputLine);
        out.flush();


    }
}

   //receiving message
public void run () throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = new Socket ("192.168.123.3",1234);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream ()));
    out = new PrintWriter (socket.getOutputStream (), true);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine ()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println ("Client <  " + inputLine);
        rxArea.setText (inputLine);
    }


    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Android Server Code

```
 public void runTcpServer(){

    handel = new Handler();
    try {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(new SettingDialog().port);
        //creating a socket to listen on a given port
        Log.i("NW LOG","PORT OPENED SUCESSFULLY in "+a);
        final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(a);

        Thread listenConnection = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    //accepting the incoming socket connection request
                    Socket workstationSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    //reading the incoming content
                   BufferedReader  readerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(workstationSocket.getInputStream()));

                   outMessage = new PrintStream(workstationSocket.getOutputStream(),true);


                    Log.i("NW LOG","WATING FOR MSG");
                    while(readerIn.readLine()!=null){

                        final String incomingMsg = readerIn.readLine();

                        //setting incoming message to UI thread using handler
                        handel.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                setMessage(IN,incomingMsg);
                            }
                        });


                    }
                    outMessage.close();
                    readerIn.close();
                    workstationSocket.close();
                    serverSocket.close();



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });listenConnection.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: `but when message is sent from Client to server` ??? There is no code that tries to send something. Nor on client side. Nor on server side. Client an server only try to read lines. That will not go if nothing is send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following code part:

```
while(readerIn.readLine()!=null){
    final String incomingMsg = readerIn.readLine();
    ....
```

In the first line you are reading the line and ignoring it. Therefore you are throwing away every second line.

The correct way to read and use it for the while loop is this:

```
String incomingMsg;
while((incomingMsg = readerIn.readLine())!=null){
      ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me out but can you elaborate more how does that happen? I didn't get it. After checking the while condition it gets inside the loop if condition satisfies and so how does that skips the first value? We are just checking the reader value not clearing or doing anything inside or outside.

Comment: Every call of `readLine()` consumes one line even if you don't assign the return value to a variable. Therefore if you call it twice for every while loop you only get every 2nd line.